# what will happen when load data fails

Tags: mysql, sql

I am doing load data from CSV-file in my master database.

My CSV-file size is 160 GB.

My questions:

1. Will Load data load in the slave parallely or not?
2. If disk gets full in master, will the entire process roll back or partially fail?

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in my personal experience when you use the import function it will fire a query for each of your line in csv... that means if you found problem on any of the lines or disks get full it will not be roll backed... so it is partially fail

& one doubt is also there that it will allow your csv to execute or not because of the size...